# Unity Camera panning when zoomed in/out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this method which pans the camera forward/back and left/right. I am not sure why, but what is causing the camera to move nice when zoomed in close to the terrain but move really slow when zoomed out?

Here is how I am panning the camera:

```
void CameraPan(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(2)){
        transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 20f, Space.World);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 20f, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am zooming:

```
void CameraZoom(){
    float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    if(scroll < 0){
        transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * scrollSpeed);
    }else if(scroll > 0){
        transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * scrollSpeed);
    }
}
```

What can I do to pan the camera at the same speed no matter if I am zoomed in or out?

Comment: As the camera gets further away from its target, lateral movement such as panning will cause less visual change -- this is why the Sun appears not to move in the sky, even after you drive hundreds of miles. Perhaps you could zoom by changing the camera's [field of view](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html), instead?

Comment: I have tried doing that, the problem is that everything looks too strange.

Answer (score 0):

calculate you zoom factor - this number can be anything that represents your zoom (for example, it can be the distance from your camera to the object in the center of your view)

use this zoom factor to multiply the Translate parameter when you calculate the CameraPan (for example - if your zoom factor is the distance, you will pan more when you are zoomed out = at a greater distance)